# TypeScript NodeJS application Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.ts(7017)

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeerror

This is `time.ts` file:

```
exports.getMinute = (timestamp: number) => {
    const milliSecond = timestamp * 1000;
    const dateObject = new Date(milliSecond);
    const minute = dateObject.toLocaleString('en-us',{minute : "number"});
    return minute;
};

exports.getHour = (timestamp: number) => {
    const milliSecond = timestamp * 1000;
    const dateObject = new Date(milliSecond);
    const hour = dateObject.toLocaleString('en-us',{hour : "number"});
    return hour;
};

exports.getDay = (timestamp: any) => {
    const milliSecond = timestamp ;
    const dateObject = new Date(milliSecond);
    
    const day = dateObject.getDate();
    return day;
};

exports.getMonth = (timestamp: any) => {
    const milliSecond = timestamp ;
    const dateObject = new Date(milliSecond);
    const month = dateObject.getMonth();
    return month;
};
exports.getYear = (timestamp: any) => {
    const milliSecond = timestamp ;
    const dateObject = new Date(milliSecond);
    const year = dateObject.getFullYear();
    return year;
};

exports.fullTime = (timestamp: any) => {
        let day = this.getDay(timestamp);
        const year = this.getYear(timestamp);
        let month = this.getMonth(timestamp);
        month ++
        return `${year}`+'-'+`${month<=9 ? '0'+ month : month }` + '-' + `${day<=9 ? '0'+ day : day }`;
};
```

I get the following errors:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis'
> has no index signature.ts(7017)
>
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis'
> has no index signature.ts(7017)
>
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis'
> has no index signature.ts(7017)

For these lines of code:

```
let day = this.getDay(timestamp);
const year = this.getYear(timestamp);
let month = this.getMonth(timestamp);
```

Also these errors:

> Type '"number"' is not assignable to type '"numeric" | "2-digit" |
> undefined'.ts(2322)
>
> Type '"number"' is not assignable to type '"numeric" | "2-digit" |
> undefined'.ts(2322)

At these lines of the code:

```
const minute = dateObject.toLocaleString('en-us',{minute : "number"});
const hour = dateObject.toLocaleString('en-us',{hour : "number"});
```

I don't know what does it mean and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to remove the errors.

`exports.` is more of a javascript construct, which you usually don't use with typescript. So, I would replace it with `export const` in all cases in your file, for example:

```js
export const getDay = (timestamp: any) => {
  const milliSecond = timestamp;
  const dateObject = new Date(milliSecond);

  const day = dateObject.getDate();
  return day;
};
```

Regarding usage of `this`, you usually want to use this when you are located in context of a class, but in your case you have separate functions. So, after changing all export statements, just call the functions directly:

```js
  let day = getDay(timestamp);
  const year = getYear(timestamp);
  let month = getMonth(timestamp);
```

As for `toLocaleString`, this is typescript trying to tell you that the value `number` that you used for `minute` and `hour` properties is not a correct value that it supports, and it suggests that you replace it with either `numeric`, `2-digit`, or just not define it (which defaults to `undefined`). So, statements like this should work:

```js
  const minute = dateObject.toLocaleString('en-us', { minute: 'numeric' });
  const hour = dateObject.toLocaleString('en-us', { hour: 'numeric' });
```

IDE usually also gives you hints, for example hovering over a property would tell you what type that property expects. In case of minute it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDG4p.png), which is a union type of 2 string values or undefined. Try hovering over other properties to give you a better idea of what type they expect.

Hope this helps :)